# Why is facebook api asking this message on login with facebook for authorised users - "Application name" would like to access your friend list.?

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-javascript-sdk

Earlier for login with facebook, it used to ask for username and password for already authorised users and login. But now its asking one more thing-

> "App name" would like to access your friend list.

Also, this is part of the basic information permissions, which user has already authorised.
Why this new behavior ?

Comment: Can you post the url to the application?

Comment: Possibly related to [this bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/528423520559440?browse=external_tasks_search_results_521472e6174b98716921665)

Comment: Facebook have fixed the bug : see https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/528423520559440

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook app authorization screen says that the app would like to access your friend’s list. But in truth, the app probably didn’t ask for that. The friends list is part of every app authorization, whether the app wants it or not. This is because Facebook wants apps to add social context, which can only be done with the friends list.

But this doesn’t give the app the ability to contact your friends on your behalf, at least not more than it could do so without you adding the app anyway.

Check for an reference

https://www.facebook.com/about/privacy/your-info-on-other#applications

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem as well, so I've been keeping an eye on the [bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/528423520559440) mentioned by a few of the other users here. It says they have a fix for this problem ready.

I just tested this again a few minutes ago; it looks like Facebook should no longer be asking for friend's list access (unless it is requested).